# SAPI 5.3 speech to Text

Tags: visual-c++, sapi

I am looking for a basic example for Speech to Text using the SAPI 5.3 on VC++.
Can you please provide with a sample program?

Answer (score 2):

The SAPI demo code is available in the Window 7 SDK. Once installed they are in SDK install dir\Samples\winui\speech\

Microsoft's MSDN website gives an overview of the available samples. 
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720406%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
These should be a good starting point.

Comment: The SDK is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx).